# WPF Dynamic TabControl SelectionChanged bug?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, mvvm, tabcontrol

I am creating a simple application using C# and WPF using the MVVM pattern. There is a main window with a few buttons and a ContentControl containing a list of view models, one of them being SearchViewModel. The buttons flip between the view models.

The SearchViewModel is bound to the SearchView and contains a TabControl. The ItemsSource property is bound to a list of SearchTabViewModels. In the constructor of SearchViewModel, I am initializing the ObservableCollection of SearchTabViewModels and then adding two tabs. The first tab has "+" for its header and the other is a normal search tab. The TabControl's SelectionChanged event is bound to a method that checks if the "+" tab was clicked. If it is, a new tab is inserted before the "+" tab and the TabControl's SelectedIndex property is set to the index of the inserted tab. Fairly simple setup.

The issue I'm having is that when the application is first run, you can click the "+" tab and insert a new tab but then the "+" tab is dead and nothing happens when you click it. The SelectionChanged event does not fire. I've checked and the SelectedIndex is set to the tab before it so it's not the selected tab. To fix it, you have to click on another tab first and then everything works fine. It just freezes that once at the beginning.

Can anybody see what the issue may be? I'm including the relevant portions of code:

XAML

```
<TabControl 
    Name="searchTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchTabs}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedTabIndex}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{Binding Source={StaticResource searchTabTemplateSelector}}">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                CommandName="searchTabHasChanged" Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=CommandName}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    ....more code
```

SearchViewModel

```
public class SearchViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
{
    #region Fields

    public ObservableCollection<SearchTabViewModel> SearchTabs { get; set; }
    private int _selectedTabIndex;
    private ICommand _selectionChangedCommand;

    #endregion

    public SearchViewModel()
    {
        try
        {
            // initialize the SearchTabs array
            this.SearchTabs = new ObservableCollection<SearchTabViewModel>();

            // add a tabItem with + in header 
            SearchTabViewModel tabAdd = new SearchTabViewModel("+");

            this.SearchTabs.Add(tabAdd);

            // add first tab
            AddTabItem();

            SelectedTabIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    #region Properties/Commands

    public int SelectedTabIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedTabIndex; }
        set
        {
            _selectedTabIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTabIndex");
        }
    }

    public ICommand SelectionChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectionChangedCommand == null)
            {
                _selectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => TabSelectionChanged(param)
                );
            }
            return _selectionChangedCommand;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void TabSelectionChanged(Object source)
    {
        if (source.ToString() == "searchTabHasChanged")
        {
            SearchTabViewModel tab = this.SearchTabs[SelectedTabIndex];

            if (tab != null && tab.Header != null)
            {
                if (tab.Header.Equals("+"))
                {
                    // add new tab
                    SearchTabViewModel addedTab = AddTabItem();

                    // select newly added tab item
                    SelectedTabIndex = this.SearchTabs.IndexOf(addedTab);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private SearchTabViewModel AddTabItem()
    {
        int count = SearchTabs.Count;

        // create new tab item
        SearchTabViewModel tab = new SearchTabViewModel();
        tab.Header = string.Format("Tab {0}", count);

        // insert tab item right before the last (+) tab item
        this.SearchTabs.Insert(count - 1, tab);

        return tab;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Also, another curious behavior I've noticed is that when you first run the application and click the "+" tab once to add a new tab and the "+" tab dies, if the application loses focus and gains focus again, the SelectionChanged event fires and a new tab is added? This behavior only happens when the "+" tab is dead. Once you fix it by clicking on another tab, this behavior disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TabSelectionChanged, you add a new TabItem and change the SelectedTabIndex right after each other. The problem is that the ItemContainerGenerator that generates the new TabItem in the view has not been triggered yet. This is done in the DataBinding phase. So when you set SelectedTabIndex, you actually set it to the (already selected) + tab.

To fix this, postpone the changing of the SelectedTabIndex by invoking the call on the dispatcher with a priority lower than DataBinding.

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => SelectedTabIndex = this.SearchTabs.IndexOf(addedTab), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: This does work with some modifications. Since the Dispatcher is not being passed in to this view model on creation, I am accessing the main UI thread using Application.Current.Dispatcher. I'm not entirely sure if that's a good idea but it works. Either way, you are correct in what the original problem was and how to fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have seen that we were in the view model :) Looks like you're using MVVM Light right? Then you can use the DispatcherHelper class!

Comment: No I'm not but I am considering switching to it. This is my first application using WPF and C# with the MVVM pattern so I'm doing it by hand. I find you learn it quicker that way. I did run across DispatcherHelper and may include it in my application if I don't switch to MVVM Light. I'm not sure if I need access to the main UI thread anywhere else though.